# Overlay mount at btrfs

Tags: linux, btrfs, overlayfs, aufs

I multiboot several distributions
which are at separate subvolumes.
They are stored in a not standardised
layout.
I have some subvolumes which I want
mounted in a layered way.
I prefere to use aufs .
For example, I want /home/myname to be mounted at every dist .
I also want some generic /use/share/bin to  be overlay mounted with the dist-specific one.
There are to many subdirs/files to maintain symlinks instead of overlay-mount.

Due to  cow-issues between btrfs and layered FS ,  I understand that I should not use layered fs together with btrfs.
I figured out that I maybe could overlay-mount read-wtiteable ext4 images , which resides on btrfs-subvols.
I suppose I  then should disable CoW for just the wm images.

In that way I could still snapshot the subvols which contains the  image-files.

I mainly would like to know if there is better solutions to combine btrfs and layered fs .